# Font not being updated properly

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm experiencing an odd scenario where my updated font is not reflected in pdf output of my latex documents.

First of all, i made my own font at FontStruct.com, and downloaded it as a true-type-font. I use it for an alien script in my sf stories, and i'm able to use in in my LaTeX documents. I use Xelatex.exe to compile them to pdfs.

However, recently i needed to make some changes to the font. So i did so and downloaded it again, and installed it simply by moving the ttf file into the C:/Windows/Fonts. Windows 7 automatically installs it, and i know the right version is installed because this is reflected whenever i use wordpad. The changes are there.

But when i compile with LaTeX, it's as if the old font never got updated. It's still using the unchanged alien font, and i never get any font-related errors in the compile log. This leads me to believe the font is cached somewhere but i can't find anything like that.

I use windows 7 pro 64-bit, with MikTex, with TeXnicCenter 2.02 64-bit, using xelatex.exe for compilations. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Can you show, at least, the line you use for choosing the font? The one with `\setmainfont`.

Comment: I use a custom command, "\newcommand{\VTGN}[1]{\setmainfont{Vortigenu}{#1}\setmainfont{Times New Roman}}". The filename of my alien font is Vortigenu.ttf. I also tested it with \setmainfont{Vortigenu}, but it produced the same result. What i'm really looking for is the cache for these programs (texniccenter, xelatex, etc) since that;s my suspicion.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I know, but i have this name on several stackexcahnges and im afraid to change it for fear that previous threads will no longer link to me. PM me if u have advice about that.

Comment: There is no cache. But perhaps you have a second version of the font somewhere. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your document and then check the log-file.

Comment: Ok, i tried that but the log was pretty long to search through. Nevertheless, i found multiple instances where it requested Vortigenu from the proper windows/fonts directory, and from what I can tell it constructed a tex-readable font from this. What else should I be looking for in the log? I didn't see any outright errors related to any fonts.

Comment: Maybe someone can explain how MikTex compiles its fonts from the windows fonts, so that I can attempt to do this manually?